# Битрикс - Как через API добавить новый адрес в список адресов в разделе Email-маркетинг

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день.
Возникла необходимость добавлять через API новый адрес в список адресов в разделе Email-маркетинг в админке Битрикса.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать название класса и функции, или дать ссылку на готовый пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sender/ это API по работе с email маркетингом. там есть все классы и объяснение как их использовать
по идее если у вас есть рассылка и вам нужно добавить в нее новый эмайл (подписать определенный эмайл на рассылку) то вот что вам нужно
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sender/subscription/subscribe.php

Comment: Спасибо, информация помогла.
В итоге нужен был метод \Bitrix\Sender\ContactTable::add()